# How can I convert nnmail-split-methods mail filtering format to Sieve format?

Tags: gnus, filtering

Any pointers to convert nnmail-split-methods to Sieve? Are there any functions in gnus, since it seems to also handle Sieve format?

I have like a few hundred lines exactly like this:

```
("ffmpeg-devel" "^\\(Mailing-List:\\|Delivered-To:\\|List-Id:\\).*ffmpeg-devel.ffmpeg.org*")
("ffmpeg-user" "^\\(Mailing-List:\\|Delivered-To:\\|List-Id:\\).*ffmpeg-user.ffmpeg.org*")
```

, so it's a very simple list.